# Tamper Monkey script to change a Style of only a div inside a class with many divs inside

Tags: tampermonkey

I am using a project tracking program (Smartsheet.com) and it displays the today line in the timeline using a dim dashed 1px line. I want to change it to 3px and color red.

Can someone help me with the script? I don't know how to target the specific div. It is inside a class div with multiple divs inside. The other divs make up the days, weeks, months divisions that I do not want to change. I just want to change the today div only.

Here is the code. The today div is the first div inside the div class="clsGAW". I want to change the *1px dashed rgb(68,68,68)* to: *3px dashed rgb(256,0,0)*

```html
<div class="clsGAW">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; width: 1px; border-left: 1px dashed rgb(68, 68, 68); background-color: transparent; z-index: 1; left: 119px; height: 1839px; display: block;"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 55px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);"></div><div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 111px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(248, 247, 245);"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 167px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(248, 247, 245);"></div><div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 223px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(248, 247, 245);"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 279px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(248, 247, 245);"></div><div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 303px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);"></div>

... mane more divs(grid)

</div>
```

Thanks for your help.
Fritz

I have very little experience making scripts with tampermonkey. I can try to target the class but wouldn't it affect all divs inside it?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you're trying to achieve. You can use the Smartsheet API to update the format of a cell in a sheet, but that doesn't sound like you're goal here. I'd suspect that it's not possible to use the Smartsheet API to change the style of the "today" line in a Smartsheet project timeline, i.e., it's part of the Smartsheet UI that's not formattable by end users. If I were you, I'd research whether or not it's possible to make your desired change via the UI -- if that's not possible, then doing it via API is almost certainly not possible.

Comment: FYI, I've added the [tampermonkey] tag to your question, as folks who have expertise with that product may be able to help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more background details on your problem. Telling readers about your research, what you have already tried, and why it didn’t meet your needs will allow them to understand it better.

Comment: @KimBrandl Maybe the Tag Smartsheet-api was misleading. It is more a UI script I'm looking for. Can you suggest a better tag?

Comment: Since you're using Tamper Monkey -- the [tampermonkey] tag is the proper tag. (I've already added it to your post.)

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the code. The today div is the first div inside the div class="clsGAW". I want to change the 1px dashed rgb(68,68,68) to: 3px dashed rgb(256,0,0)

If it is always the first `div`, it can be done with CSS.
Note: you can also use `border-left: 3px dashed #f00 !important;` which is the same.

```css
div.clsGAW > div:first-of-type {
  border-left: 3px dashed rgb(255,0,0) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="clsGAW">
  <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; width: 1px; border-left: 1px dashed rgb(68, 68, 68); background-color: transparent; z-index: 1; left: 119px; height: 1839px; display: block;">DIV 1</div>
  <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 55px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);">DIV 2</div>
  <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 111px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(248, 247, 245);">DIV 3</div>
  <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 167px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(248, 247, 245);">DIV 4</div>
  <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 223px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(248, 247, 245);">DIV 5</div>
  <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 279px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(248, 247, 245);">DIV 6</div>
  <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 303px; height: 1839px; width: 1px; display: block; background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);">DIV 7</div>

  <!-- ... mane more divs(grid) -->
</div>
```

A userscript can be made to apply the CSS. For example:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Style a div
// @description   Tamper Monkey script to change a Style
// @match         *://*.example.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

const css = 
`div.clsGAW > div:first-of-type {
  border-left: 3px dashed rgb(255,0,0) !important;
}`;

GM_addStyle(css);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't know you could target the first div that way. I tried your solution but did not worked.

here is the script:
`// ==UserScript==
// @name         Change Style
// @description  Tamper Monkey script to change a Style
// @author       erosman @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76210508/tamper-monkey-script-to-change-a-style-of-only-a-div-inside-a-class-with-many-di/76353321#76353321

// ==/UserScript==


const css =
`div.clsGAW > div:first-of-type {
  border-left: 3px dashed rgb(255,0,0) !important;
}`;

GM_addStyle(css);`

Comment: @FritzBorrego If you give a webpage to test the script on, I can test and see.

Comment: Its behind a login which I can't share. If you open a free trial account with [smartsheet] (smartsheet.com) you could open a project template and see the **gant view**. The today line is a faint dashed black line. You would go above and beyond if you do this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it difficult to find out what is happening without testing. You can check by opening the Developer Tools in the browser.

Comment: Here is an image of the file. 

[![HrLlpLP.th.png](https://iili.io/HrLlpLP.th.png)](https://freeimage.host/i/HrLlpLP)

As you can see tamper monkey is running and the today line is un affected. 

Here is a picture of the code. Maybe is something wrong with the code. 
[![HrL0b8G.th.png](https://iili.io/HrL0b8G.th.png)](https://freeimage.host/i/HrL0b8G)

Or maybe it is not the first div.

[![HrL1q8b.th.png](https://iili.io/HrL1q8b.th.png)](https://freeimage.host/i/HrL1q8b)

Comment: @FritzBorrego Unfortunately, those images don't show enough to reach a conclusion.